# Python - Tabula - OpenType Layout tables used in font not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored

Tags: python, pdf, tabula

This is the code run in a Pycharm with tabula installed.

import tabula

tabula.convert_into('https://www.northonline.com.au/content/dam/product/north/summit_investment_options.pdf', "output.csv", output_format='csv', pages='3')

I receive this error, some of the data is produced but not all. It leaves out the table.

Got stderr: May 14, 2020 3:49:39 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 
INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font GFEDCB+Archer-MediumLining are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored

Running the same code with pages set to 'all' just produces additional errors.

Is there a way to add fonts, or to extract the missed data?

Comment: "INFO" is not an "error". And it is not relevant for text / table extraction.

Answer (score 0):

"INFO" is not an error, the reason why "some of the data is produced, but not all" is basically because of the PDF embedded structure.

But if you definitely wanted to get those missing data, then you can try using an another approach by using [CAMELOT](https://readthedocs.org/projects/camelot-py/downloads/pdf/master/) library. That will give you the missing data's.